# ORDS defaults.xml vs conf/<name>.xml File Upload <entry key="apex.docTable">schema.doc_upload_table</entry>

Tags: oracle, oracle-ords, mod-plsql

When trying to get File Upload to work, I added

`<entry key="apex.docTable">schema.doc_upload_table</entry>`

to both defaults.xml and conf/.xml.  I realized later that, because we will be using this for multiple databases, we should not specify the name in the defaults.xml file but only in the conf/.xml file.

I have tried to remove the entry in the defaults.xml file but I get the original error:

> Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: line 2, column 2:
>   PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'UPLOAD_PROC'
>   ORA-06550: line 2, column 2: PL/SQL: Statement ignored

Do I have to do additional steps to remove an entry from defaults.xml and have it look instead in conf/.xml for the name of the apex.docTable?

Answer (score 0):

In ORDS3 the upload information has to be in the defaults.xml file.  We upgraded to ORDS18 and it no longer has to be in the defaults.xml file.  We were able to place it in conf/.xml.  This is what we needed because we have more than one database and each database has a different upload table name.

Comment: I guess you could now close the question